# Remove user direct access in folder sharepoint Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, sharepoint

I aim to remove a user's direct access to a Sharepoint folder using typescript.
I am occupying `sp-pnp-node` and `@ pnp / login`.
I can already assign the permissions without any problem, but I can't find the way for remove it :(

[image: Example]

The user does not belong to any group and has specific permissions per folder.

Comment: Tried to improve the question text.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need:

Use `import "@pnp/sp/security";` to load the PnP security module.

```
const userToRemove = //get a reference to the user object for the user

sp.web.roleAssignments.expand("Member").get().then(function(assignments) { 
    assignments.forEach(function(role) {
        if (role.Member.Id == userToRemove.Id) {
            await list.roleAssignments.getById(role.Id).delete();
        }
    });
});
```

For more details on the security module, see https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/security/#role-assignments